# MySQL Join, Show all Rows from one table linking to another with Highest ID

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, join

I have a couple of tables that I am linking. I have a `users` table:

```
+----------+
|   Users  |
|----------|
| id       |
| email    |
| password |
| etc...   |
+----------+
```

A `profiles` table

```
+-------------+
|  Profiles   |
|-------------|
| profile_id  |
| user_id     |
| first_name  |
| etc...      |
+-------------+
```

And a `Subscriptions` table:

```
+-----------------+
|  Subscriptions  |
|-----------------|
| subscription_id |
| user_id         |
| start_date      |
| end_date        |
+-----------------+
```

The `data` looks like this:

```
Users:
------
id: 1
email: Josh@example.com
password: j2jahfu7329 (this is hashed)

Profiles:
---------
profile_id: 1
user_id: 1
first_name: Josh

Subscriptions (There can be multiple for a single user and they can backdate):
-------------
subscription_id: 1
user_id: 1
start_date: 2015/03/01
end_date: 2015/04/01

subscription_id: 2
user_id: 1
start_date: 2015/04/01
end_date: 2015/05/01

subscription_id: 3
user_id: 1
start_date: 2015/02/01
start_date: 2016/02/01
```

I need to loop through and return every user in the database, along with their profile details, and the `latest` subscription according to the `subscription_id`.

I have tried quite a lot of ways over the last few hours, and the closest I have gotten is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(subscriptions.subscription_id), subscriptions.end_date, subscriptions.user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE subscriptions.user_id = users.id) AS subs 
ON subs.user_id = users.id
```

BUT that only returns the FIRST user in the database with the latest subscription id even the one that does not belong to that user.

I am trying to do this in Laravel, but have now started just writing the query in phpmyadmin first to get it right.

What do I need to do to get the result I am expecting? (result below)

```
id: 1
email: josh@example.com
password: j2jahfu7329
profile_id: 1
first_name: Josh,
subscription_id: 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you set on using the query builder?  This is a fantastic opportunity to dive into Eloquent relationships and it would be perfect for this.

Comment: I have tried that, but am not succeeding

Comment: What laravel version are you using?

Comment: @Richie I am using 4.2